does this ROC curve and the ROC AUC score really match?
I am working on a binary classification problem. I tried to evaluate a model by plotting ROC  curve and calculating ROC AUC score. The calculated score is 0.9115 but the curve area looks not releastic for this score. I tried to calculate the area roughly by dividing it into rectange and triangle and then sum the area of those but that gives me around 0.7 (I am not sure if what I did to calculate the area is correct). Any ideas?


That curve definitely has an area under it of 0.7. How did you plot that curve? It looks like you may have used the categorical predictions to get just three points instead of using the raw predictions you used when you did that AUC calculation to get 0.9115.

That's what I thought. I used predict_propa as in here :
test_pred_prob = predict_proba(test_features)
roc_auc = roc_auc_score(test_target, test_pred_prob[:,1]). When I used the actual class predictions instead of prediction probabilities I get 0.69, is that true though?

@Dave You are right! In plotting the curve I used the actual categorical predictions! I was focusing on the score thinking it is the one wrong! Now changed to probabilities for the curve and now makes sense! Thank yo!

Perhaps you could post a self-answer to “close out” this question.

Based on @Dave comment, I found the issue. The ROC curve was plotted using the actual class predictions, where it should have been the predictions probabilities which can be calculated using predict_proba method. Changing this gave the correct plot.

What do you mean by the "actual" class predictions? In order to calculate the sensitivity-specificity pairs in the ROC curve, you need class predictions to compare to the observed classes.

I meant the categorical predictions like 0 or 1, while roc curve method expects the probabilities of predictions.

But how do you get those categorical predictions? Are they unique? If they are unique, how do you get the other points on the ROC curve?

Those are the class predictions using predict method. I did not get the second part of your question.

Think about how a ROC curve is created. It is a bunch of sensitivity-specificity pairs, right?
